# Export shapefile with "non standard" characters to csv and read in excel

Tags: qgis, export, csv, encoding

Macbook air mid 2011 running OSX 10.10.5
QGIS 2.8.2 - Wien
Excel 15.13.1 (O365)

When I export a shapefile containing non-ascii characters to a csv file using QGIS (setting encoding to utf-8) and importing to excel I end up with weird characters. What encoding (export and import) should I use?

for example:
Darién becomes DariÃ©n

A workaround is uploading the QGIS exported csv file with utf-8 encoding to google docs and download it as an xlsx file but there must be a more elegant solution

The way I export the shapefile is by using right mouse button on the layer and choose save as. In the dialog window I choose csv

Comment: look at [Solved: Editing a CSV with UTF-8 encoding on a Mac](http://rothmanshore.com/2013/10/29/solved-editing-a-csv-with-utf-8-encoding-on-a-mac/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try export to other format: gml, after that rename

> .gml to .txt

and import to excel.